# Dynamically change onmouseover or onmouseout to call a different function

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to change a function that is called by an existing onmouseover or onmouseout event?  For the following example is there a way for me to have ChangeItemAEvent change the "ItemA" onmouseover function from ChangeColor() to ChangeColorBack()? Currently I need to declare an entirely new function() that I feel is not elegant because I am repeating code when I should be able to call an existing function.

javascript:

```
function ChangeColor(elementid)
{
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.background = "Orange";
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.color = "Black";
}

function ChangeColorBack(elementid)
{
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.background = "Black";
  document.getElementById(elementid).style.color = "White";
}

function ChangeItemAEvent()
{
  document.getElementById("ItemA").onmouseover = function() {

    document.getElementById("ItemA").style.background = "Black";
  document.getElementById("ItemA").style.color = "White";

  };
}
```

html:

```
<span id="ItemA" onmouseover="ChangeColor(this.id)">
<button id="ButtonB" onclick="ChangeItemAEvent()">
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this

```
function ChangeItemAEvent()
{
    document.getElementById("ItemA").onmouseover = function() {ChangeColorBack(this.id)};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to change a function that is called by an existing onmouseover or onmouseout event?

Yes, by writing to the DOM `element.onmouseover` property, with a function value. This can be a function name or an inline function expression.

If you do all your scripting by writing to event handler properties (or adding event listeners) you can take advantage of `this` pointing to the element and avoid passing around IDs, which makes it easier:

```
<span id="ItemA">
<button type="button" id="ButtonB">

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ChangeColor() {
        this.style.background= 'orange';
        this.style.color= 'black';
    }

    function ChangeColorBack(elementid) {
        this.style.background= 'black';
        this.style.color= 'white';
    }

    document.getElementById('ItemA').onmouseover= ChangeColor;
    document.getElementById('ButtonB').onclick= function() {
        document.getElementById('ItemA').onmouseover= ChangeColorBack;
    };
</script>
```

However for this sort of hover-and-select work you are usually better off using state variables or CSS instead of re-assigning event handlers. For example something like:

```
#ItemA:hover { background: orange; color: black; }
#ItemA.selected:hover { background: black; color: white; }

document.getElementById('ButtonB').onclick= function() {
    var a= document.getElementById('ItemA');
    a.className= a.className==='selected'? '' : 'selected';
};
```

(`:hover` on a span doesn't work in IE6, so if you need to make that browser hover-highlight you would have to have `onmouseover`/`mouseout` code to add or remove a `.hover` className.)